# RestTemplate transforming parameters values into Singleton Arrays

Tags: java, rest, web-services, resttemplate

as the title says , I'm having trouble with setting parameters to the rest template.

First of all , here is the code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    params.add("place_id","7" );
    params.add("name","Winsrow" );
    params.add("phone","111333222" );

    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    headers.add("Authorization",  AUTHORIZATION);
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(params, headers);

   String response = restTemplate.postForObject(CREATE_SHIPMENT_URL, request, String.class);
```

Im using the string as a response just to consume the WS response. Here is the problem :

RestTemplate in some point of the process , is transforming the value of my map of params (no the key) into arrays with single object (this object containing the value of the map key) like this (on the server side):

```
 $info = object(stdClass) {
place_id => array(
    (int) 0 => '7'
)
name => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Winsrow'
)
phone => array(
    (int) 0 => '111333222'
)
```

What can I do in order to prevent this transformation ? 
Cheers !

Comment: You used a `MultiValueMap` which by definition has arrays as the values. Everything is working exactly as intended. In HTTP parameters can have multiple values so they are arrays.

Comment: Yeah, use a simple `HashMap` if you want normal-looking JSON representation.

Comment: @Jai I don't know how I transform my MultiValueMap into HashMaps , can you give me an example please?

Comment: Just change the type to `HashMap`. Do note that if you expect attributes to contain more than one value (e.g. 2 phone numbers) within a single web service call, then you have to continue with what you have now. You need a list to hold the attribute and so JSON has represented it this way - which is correct.

Comment: @Jai  Thanks man!

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks for the answer man!